# Find matching values and their frequencies from multiple list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python. Suppose I have multiple list of lists (in this case, 2 ). Example:

**List A** `[ ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'] , ['q', 'w', 'a', 'c'] ]`

**List B**  `[ ['a', 'p', 'z', 'c', 'q'] , ['a', 'l', 'k', 'j'] ]`.

I want to compare list A and list B, and find the specific elements along with their frequencies that occur in both the lists. In this case I want the answer to be 'q', 'a' and 'c'.  But I don't want to count 'a' occurring in list A or in any of the sub-lists of list A.

Considering element 'a' from List A, I just want to know whether 'a' is also seen in List B, and count that occurrence as frequency = 2, but say 'b' is only seen in List A, so it's frequency is 1 only. I also want to know the name of the lists in which the element has been seen, so for 'a', the answer would be List A and List B, but for 'b' it is only List A.

The basic intuition is to track the values that are more spread (that is, present in more number of lists) compared to other values. Is there an efficient way of doing this ? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain your question more clearly? I don't see the connection between the difference in lists and the character frequencies

Comment: Since the answer should be 'q', 'a' and 'c' what do you mean by more spread?  Although 'a' appears in all sublists, 'q' only appears once in List A and List B.

Comment: @Danny Adding to the above mentioned, considering element 'a'  from List A, I just want to know whether 'a' is also seen in List B, and count that occurrence as frequency = 2, but say 'b' is only seen in List A, so it's frequency is 1 only. I also want to know the name of the lists in which the element has been seen, so for 'a', the answer would be List A and List B, but for 'b' it is only List A.

Comment: @DarrylG By more spread I mean, which values are seen in more number of lists (List A and List B in this case). I have a larger number of list of lists and have stated 2 here for the sake of simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: So are you looking for elements that appear in all lists?  Items 'a', 'c', 'q' have a count of 2 (i.e. they appear in the two lists). 
 With n list List1, List2, ... Listn, are you looking for the elements that appear in all n lists (so has a count of n)?

Comment: @DarrylG Not all lists, and that is why I would want the frequency, suppose I have 3 lists and 'a' is not present in any sub-list of the third list, then also I would like to output the element 'a' with frequency= 2, and also a note of the lists in which I saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following reports counts on occurrences of items across lists

```
def flatten(lst):
    " Flattens into single lists "
    return [val for sublist in lst for val in sublist]

def occurences(*lsts):
    " Takes in an arbitrary number of lists and reports frequencies of items "
    result = {}
    for i, lst in enumerate(lsts):
        f_lst = flatten(lst)
        for c in f_lst:
            result.setdefault(c, set()).add(i)
    # Add frequencies
    # key frequency is the count
    # key occurs is which numbered list of the item
    final = {}
    for c, s in result.items():
        final[c] = {'frequency': len(s), 'occurs':list(s)}
    return final
```

**Usage**

```
stats = occurrences(List1, List2, ..., ListN)
```

**Test**

Test 1 (ListA & ListB are references as 0, 1 in occurs)

```
ListA = [ ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'] , ['q', 'w', 'a', 'c'] ]
ListB = [ ['a', 'p', 'z', 'c', 'q'] , ['a', 'l', 'k', 'j'] ]
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(occurences(ListA, ListB))
{'a': {'frequency': 2, 'occurs': [0, 1]},
 'b': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [0]},
 'c': {'frequency': 2, 'occurs': [0, 1]},
 'd': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [0]},
 'j': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [1]},
 'k': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [1]},
 'l': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [1]},
 'p': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [1]},
 'q': {'frequency': 2, 'occurs': [0, 1]},
 'w': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [0]},
 'z': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [1]}}
```

Test 2 (ListA, ListB, ListC referenced as 0, 1, 2 in occurs)

```
ListA = [ ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'] , ['q', 'w', 'a', 'c'] ]
ListB = [ ['a', 'p', 'z', 'c', 'q'] , ['a', 'l', 'k', 'j'] ]
ListC = [ ['m', 'p', 'r', 's', 'q'] , ['a', 't', 'k', 'j'] ]
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(occurences(ListA, ListB, ListC))

{'a': {'frequency': 3, 'occurs': [0, 1, 2]},
 'b': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [0]},
 'c': {'frequency': 2, 'occurs': [0, 1]},
 'd': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [0]},
 'j': {'frequency': 2, 'occurs': [1, 2]},
 'k': {'frequency': 2, 'occurs': [1, 2]},
 'l': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [1]},
 'm': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [2]},
 'p': {'frequency': 2, 'occurs': [1, 2]},
 'q': {'frequency': 3, 'occurs': [0, 1, 2]},
 'r': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [2]},
 's': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [2]},
 't': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [2]},
 'w': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [0]},
 'z': {'frequency': 1, 'occurs': [1]}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. Is there a way to add lists easily in `pp(occurences(ListA, ListB, ListC))`, as I am having over 100 lists?

Comment: @Are the lists ListA, ListB, ListC, etc. sublist of a larger list ie.. `my_big_list = [List1, List2, List3, ...List100]`?  If so, result = occurences(*my_big_list)`.  Or is there some other organization of your lists?

Comment: My lists are stored in a dictionary: the pattern is dict = { string : (list of lists) }, where list of lists is list 1 ... N

Comment: In that case, it may make more sense to change `def occurences(*lsts):` to `def occurences(lsts):` and `for i, lst in enumerate(lsts):` to `for i, lst in lsts.items():` and call it with the dictionary as the single argument to `occurences`

Comment: @SaranyaGupta--with `d = { string : (list of lists) }`, you would have `result = occurences(*d[string])`